# Issues with a search filter using stencil component

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, sharepoint, stenciljs

So I have a filter component on a sharepoint website where you can search for new by inputing some text (can be from the title or the description) but lately I'm face sort of tricky problem. For two users, where the search is made by text input throws an error (See image below), but it works for all other users. Does anybody here face something similar?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouGzs.png)

Here's the code:

```js
import {
  Component,
  Host,
  h,
  Prop,
  Event,
  EventEmitter,
  Element,
} from "@stencil/core";
import { uniqueCategorias } from "./../../utils/utils";

export interface SearchData {
  dtInicio?: string;
  dtFim?: string;
  categoria?: string;
  texto?: string;
  isFilter?: boolean;
}

@Component({
  tag: "snt-noticias-cards-filtro",
  styleUrl: "noticias-cards-filtro.scss",
  shadow: true,
})
export class SntNoticiasCardsFiltro {
  @Element() private element: HTMLElement;
  get ddlCategoria(): any {
    return this.element.shadowRoot.querySelector("#ddlCategoria") as any; //vai buscar a categoria selecionada no filtro
  }
  //faz a lista de categorias para colocar na dropdown
  get allddlCategoria(): NodeListOf<HTMLElement> {
    return this.element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(
      "ul > snt-option"
    ) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
  }

  get dtInicio(): any {
    return this.element.shadowRoot.querySelector("#dtInicio") as any;
  }

  get dtFim(): any {
    return this.element.shadowRoot.querySelector("#dtfim") as any;
  }
  get txtPesquisar(): HTMLInputElement {
    return this.element.shadowRoot.querySelector(
      "#txtPesquisar"
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
  }

  @Event({ eventName: "search", bubbles: false }) search: EventEmitter<
    SearchData
  >;

  @Prop() disable: boolean = true;
  @Prop() categorias: any[];
  @Prop() itenSelect: string;

  categoriasFilter: any[] = [];

  async componentDidLoad() {
    this.categoriasFilter = uniqueCategorias(this.categorias);
  }
  //vai buscar as informações ao filtro 
  async searchHandler(event?: CustomEvent) {
    this.search.emit({
      categoria: this.itenSelect,
      texto: this.txtPesquisar.value,
      dtInicio: await this.dtInicio.getDate(),
      dtFim: await this.dtFim.getDate(),
    });

    event && event.stopPropagation();
  }
  //Ao mudar de categoria
  changeDllCategoria({ detail }) {
    this.itenSelect = detail;
  }
  //limpa o filtro
  clear() {
    this.txtPesquisar.value = null;
    this.dtInicio.clearDate();
    this.dtFim.clearDate();
    this.itenSelect = "";
    this.ddlCategoria.setValue("");
    this.searchHandler();
  }
}
```

```html
  render() {
    this.categoriasFilter = uniqueCategorias(this.categorias);
    return (
      <Host>
        <section class="news-filter">
          <div class="news-filter-inner">
            <div class="news-filter-content">
              <div class="news-filter-content-data">
                <snt-dropdown
                  id="ddlCategoria"
                  class="dropdown1"
                  placeholder="Categoria"
                  onValueChange={this.changeDllCategoria.bind(this)}
                  isClearable={true}
                >
                  <snt-option value="">Todas as Categorias</snt-option>
                  {this.categoriasFilter.map((item: any) => {
                    return (
                      <snt-option
                        value={item.Label}
                        selected={item.Label === this.itenSelect}
                      >
                        {item.Label}
                      </snt-option>
                    );
                  })}
                </snt-dropdown>
                <spfx-datepicker
                  id="dtInicio"
                  datepicker-id="single-date-picker"
                  place-holder="Data Inicio"
                ></spfx-datepicker>
                <spfx-datepicker
                  id="dtfim"
                  datepicker-id="single-date-picker"
                  place-holder="Data Fim"
                ></spfx-datepicker>
                <snt-input-text
                  id="txtPesquisar"
                  tipo="text"
                  placeholder="Pesquise uma Notícia"
                ></snt-input-text>
              </div>
              <div class="news-filter-button">
              <snt-button
                  text="APLICAR"
                  type="apply"
                  onBtnClick={this.searchHandler.bind(this)}
                ></snt-button>
                &nbsp;
                <snt-button
                  text="LIMPAR"
                  type="clean"
                  onBtnClick={this.clear.bind(this)}
                ></snt-button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </Host>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Those errors seem to come from code you have not posted (`categoriaClass`, `normalize`). Can you post that code?

Comment: @Thomas It's funny because i don't even find that inside my code, maybe it is an artifact created by google chrome??

Comment: Very unlikely since "categoriaClass" is not English. Is it possible that specific user has an old version of the code, perhaps because of the cache or a service worker?

Comment: @Thomas That's what thought too, but I did a search in the code, and didn't find it! But now that you talk about the specific users having a older version of the code, that might be the cause, I will check it out, and I will also search again for that specific class. Thanks for the tip and sorry for the delay on responding